# htaccess / 404 issue for specific files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have recently uploaded a new site and therefore had to redirect certain pages.
There are some pages from the old site which are fine to 404, so the client can do whatever they need to do at their end.

The problem I have is that these do not throw a 404.

Example:
On the new site I have `/servers` and then furthermore: `/servers/hp`
These are in the htaccess file as: `RewriteRule ^servers servers.php [NC]` and `RewriteRule ^servers/([^/\.]+)/?$ server.php?s=$1 [L]`

However, on the old site there was a file `/servers/hp-alphaserver.php` - this does not exist anymore - but there is no 404, instead it shows the page for `/servers`

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}servers/([^/\.]+)/$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^servers/([^/\.]+)/[^/]+$ 404.php [L]
```

This checks to see if the file actually exists.